# Can a Slowed creature, whose speed has been further reduced, stand up from prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, prone

[A slowed creature moving through difficult terrain would move at 1/4 speed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/175160/do-grappled-grappling-creatures-bypass-ballbearings-caltrops). [c.f](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201588/how-does-a-slowed-creature-move-through-caltrops).

The Slow spell, among others, halves a target's speed:

> An affected target's speed is halved

A Slow, prone target has just enough remaining movement to stand, since standing up from prone:

> costs an amount of Movement equal to half your
> speed

But, what if that speed is further reduced?

If Slowed creature's speed has been reduced by e.g. caltrops, which (on a failed saving throw) have an effect:

> Until the creature regains at least 1 hit point, its walking speed is
> reduced by 10 feet.

and then it is knocked prone, can it stand up?

Comment: This question seems to be asking the same thing as the linked question, so I've closed it as a duplicate.

Comment: Understood. Makes sense to me